# How to link a picture to a user in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

What is the proper way to setup an image field in a MySQL table using phpmyadmin...?

For example, after the user registers I want them to upload a picture.
**MySQL** will link to the picture and associate it with the user.

What is the best way to store the association?

Comment: Do you mean a varchar containing the url to the img?

Comment: There are two ways: either you upload the picture somewhere on your server, and store the URL in MySQL, or you store the picture in MySQL directly (as a BLOB). Usually, the first way is recommended.

Comment: I wouldn't store the URL, but only the file name and maybe a relative path in the database. The actual base path is a setting in your server application, and the url is generated by that same server application which is probably written in PHP or something. No need or sense to store an url or even a full path in the MySQL database. It will only make your application less flexible.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let the user upload a picture and store it's entire content in your database as a `BLOB` or you could store the path to the file in a `VARCHAR` field. I would recommend the later.

Sample user table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `user` (
     user_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     user_name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
     user_picture varchar(255)
 );
```

Comment: using the varchar, where do i store the path? and how do I make it so each image uploaded can be associated to the user? how to do auto incremental image renaming on upload? (is there a script for this?) thanks

Comment: When the user uploads a picture you store it's path in the user_picture field. You could first check if a file with the same name already exists and rename it if needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`serial`, `name`, `description`, `price`, `picture`) VALUES
(1, 'View Sonic LCD', '19" View Sonic Black LCD, with 10 months warranty', 250, 'images/lcd.jpg'),
(2, 'IBM CDROM Drive', 'IBM CDROM Drive', 80, 'images/cdrom-drive.jpg'),
(3, 'Laptop Charger', 'Dell Laptop Charger with 6 months warranty', 50, 'images/charger.jpg'),
(4, 'Seagate Hard Drive', '80 GB Seagate Hard Drive in 10 months warranty', 40, 'images/hard-drive.jpg'),
(5, 'Atech Mouse', 'Black colored laser mouse. No warranty', 5, 'images/mouse.jpg'),
(6, 'Nokia 5800', 'Nokia 5800 XpressMusic is a mobile device with 3.2" widescreen display brings photos, video clips and web content to life', 299, 'images/mobile.jpg');
```